How do I "leave this conversation" when messages from a group thread are arriving via email and do not appear in the messages app?

At some point, my elderly parents started creating message threads with various family members, and in creating the thread, instead of selecting my phone number, they somehow manage to select my gmail email address.
(I don't think it's their fault, honestly, I have caught my phone default-selecting an email address before when I tap a name, but that is a separate issue.)
I keep getting these emails, which arrive via a phonenumber@vzwpix.com email address.
I would love to be able to remove myself from these threads and have them re-add my phone number, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  If they appeared in my messages app, I would just use the "leave this conversation" feature, but they don't appear in the messages app.  They only come to me via email.
Is there a way to do this?
I tried to talk my mom through removing me from the thread, but even via an iPad FaceTime session, I couldn't figure out how to do it.  What ways can I mitigate this issue?

The Messages app doesn't send email at all. They are apparently adding you as a recipient to emails they send from an email program. Depending on what that program is, you may have to remove your address from a list of contacts. That's all one can say from the information provided.

@LincDavis Actually, many/most cell carriers can deliver text messages as emails. vzwpix.com is Verizon's MMS gateway according to https://www.reddit.com/r/verizon/comments/17mlw9g/was_this_safe_to_open_emails_from_vzwpixcom_with/.

In view of @Wowfunhappy’s comment, I was mistaken. Check whether iMessage is enabled on the sending device.

iMessage is definitely on on my parents' phones and they are definitely sending to me using my email instead of my number. When you tap the group, then my contact, my gmail shows as "recent", i.e. that was the destination used when sending. I don't know whether they started typing my email in the "to" field or whether they typed and tapped my name (and it defaulted to my email).

In your iMessage account settings, are you set up to receive at that address? If you are, try sending yourself a test message.

Not at that address. They're sending to my gmail and their texts are going to my gmail... I tried sending an SMS to my gmail email address. It sent and I received an email from myphonenumber@tmomail.net (I'm T-Mobile.) The messages app does not show the received message - only sent, but Apple stopped supporting messages to self a year or so ago, so that's not saying much. There is not an option in the settings to be able to receive messages from gmail.

I just sent myself test messages from a Mac and an iPhone, so it is supported. You can add your Gmail address to your Apple Account by following the instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102529

The @vzwpix sending address indicates these are text messages from a Verizon phone, being sent via Verizon's email-to-text service.
The simplest solution is probably for your family members to just disable email-to-text. Ask them to text "Off" to 4040.
https://www.verizon.com/about/account-security/email-to-text-faqs

I'm very familiar with email-to-text. (I used to use that feature to send myself messages from my custom home automation system.) It's so you can send an email to, (e.g.), 5555555555@cellproviderdomain.com & it will (as the name suggests) convert the email to an SMS message. That's not what they did. It's the opposite. They sent a text to an email & something is converting that sms(?) to an email, so I'm not convinced what you describe happening is actually what's happening. Regardless, I don't want to disable their email-to-text service. I just want to remove myself from the thread.

In fact the link you posted explains it. The question is, what's converting the message? I don't know whether the thread is an SMS or iMessage. I haven't seen whether the bubbles are green or blue, but my guess is that it was sent as an SMS. And I'm guessing there must exist a converse text-to-email service verizon provides, that sends an email, and converts the "from" field from a phone number to their phonenumber@vzwpix.com address, which again, is the opposite of email-to-text, which converts the "to" field to a phone number as an SMS. Looking at one RN from my home automations.
